# Google Analytics Event Tracking reporting inflated event values

Tags: google-analytics

We recently released two typefaces on our website for free (albeit suggesting an optional donation). I decided we should track downloads through Google Analytics using the event feature, so we ended up adding the corresponding JS snippet to the download form (on submit), something akin to this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Typeface', 'Download', 'Typeface #1', parseInt($('input[name=amount]').val(), 10) || 0]);
```

I also decided we might as well use GA to keep track of donations, so as you might have noticed the optional donation amount is being sent as the event value argument. There's already a browser-side numeric-only verification, and it will set it to 0 in case it's empty (NaN), so we're completely sure it's always an integer (required type for the argument).

I configured two different goals (one for each typeface) in our GA profile, using the two different events as their respective conditions, as recommended by every howto I've been reading about this subject.

However, some of the reported data appears to be somewhat inflated. According to GA there's been, as of now, 455 unique events out of 550 total events, which seems to be okay, but apparently it's worth a value of **over a million dollars**. And, believe me on this, we have not received such a huge amount, at least just yet.

According to GA: *Event Value is the total value of an event or set of events. It is calculated by multiplying the per-event value by the number of times the event occurred.*

I assumed I could set individual values to different instances of the same event, even GA documentation leads me to believe so with their examples, so I don't really understand why it's being reported as such an inflated total value.

Is there something wrong with my assumption? Is this the correct approach to what I'm trying to accomplish? should I just forget about keeping track of donations using this method and resort to using the e-commerce feature instead as I've also been reading about?

I'm not checking for any verification of a donation successfully completing, so I'm left with an estimate and I'm okay with that. Maybe someone jokingly wrote off some exaggerated amount then never completed the donation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is right : you could set individual values to each event and "the report adds the total values based on each event count" (as explain in [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Values)).

The main problem with your approach is the one you mentioned : you count the donation at form validation, before its confirmation and even before you told your visitor that the donation must be made via PayPal. So yes : some people probably wrote off some exaggerated amount or simply not complete the donation process.

I recommend you to use e-commerce tracking after the PayPal payment to avoid unconfirmed donation tracking and the lack of deduplication using goals values to monitor amounts.

Comment: That sounds about right. Further investigation proved there were two instances of extremely high input. I just wanted a quick estimation for donations performed so setting up e-commerce tracking seems somewhat overkill to me, also, the link to go "back" PayPal provides to non-business users is kind of confusing, and it seems you have to put the code in the "thank you" page otherwise it won't work as expected.